# how can I add a new logo when scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script to change color in the navbar, when scrolling the page down. But, i need change image in the "logo" class, when scrolling down too.

this is the script Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()){
            $('nav').addClass('color');
            //$('logo').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
        }else{
            $('nav').removeClass('color');
        }
    })
</script>
```

This is a next line with the logo on navbar:

```
<body>
<nav>
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo-branco.png"></a>
    </div>
```

i need change to image "logo-dark.png" located in same folder img/logo-dark.png

This is the style.less:

```
nav.color{
background: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```js
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()){
         $('.default-logo').hide();
          $('.dark-logo').show();
        }else{ 
          $('.dark-logo').hide();
         $('.default-logo').show();
        }
    })
```

```css
.default-logo{
  display: none;
}



/* extra */
body{
  height: 3000px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo" class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="default-logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ff0000/ffffff">
          <img class="dark-logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/999999/ffffff">
        </a>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/br18ohc9/10/

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
$('logo').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
```

was a good start. But your selector was wrong.

```
$('.logo img').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
```